# How to get date by sending day name to strtotime function php

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

i have day name i want to get only this week date by using that day name

`date("d", strtotime('sun'));`

this function returning next Sunday date.

i need only present week date how can i get that anyone help me thanks in advance

Comment: In your calendar `Sunday` is the first day of the week?

Comment: yes but i need date of that day name in this week how can i get work done that

Answer (score 0):

```
// PHP program to display sunday as first day of a week 

// l will display the name of the day 
// d, m and Y will display the day, month and year respectively 

// For current week the time-string will be "sunday -1 week" 
// here -1 denotes last week 
$firstday = date('l - d/m/Y', strtotime("sunday -1 week")); 
echo "First day of this week: ", $firstday, "\n"; 

// For previous week the time-string wil be "sunday -2 week" 
// here -2 denotes week before last week 
$firstday = date('l - d/m/Y', strtotime("sunday -2 week")); 
echo "First day of last week: ", $firstday, "\n"; 

// For next week the time-string wil be "sunday 0 week" 
// here 0 denotes this week 
$firstday = date('l - d/m/Y', strtotime("sunday 0 week")); 
echo "First day of next week: ", $firstday, "\n"; 

// For week after next week the time-string wil be "sunday 1 week" 
// here 1 denotes next week 
$firstday = date('l - d/m/Y', strtotime("sunday 1 week")); 
echo "First day of week after next week : ", $firstday;
```

Comment: i mean it is the dynamic value it may be Sunday to Saturday any day

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Laravel, you can take advantage of the `Carbon` library, and use it like this:

```
Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('D', 'Sun')->format('d-m-Y');

// result 
// 28-04-2019
```

Comment: @JagadeeshGubbala it is good practice to select the answer that helped you as accepted answer, or write down a solution that you used it might help other devs as well.